# Adding Validation fields for email format on submitting

Tags: angular, forms, validation, email

I need to add validation to angular form to make sure the user submitted the form with email format for editing operation, I did not use formBuilder, and I hope to find a solution without formBuilder or formgroup . my HTML code is :

```
                           <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="fromEmail">From Email</label>
                                <input type="email"  required name="fromEmail" #fromEmail="ngModel" id="fromEmail" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" [(ngModel)]="currentForm.subscribers.subscriber[0].fromEmail" class="form-control" required minlength="1" maxlength="100" />
                                <div class="color" *ngIf="!fromEmail.valid">from Email is required</div>
                                <div *ngIf="submitted && fromEmail.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <div *ngIf="fromEmail.value !== '' && fromEmail.untouched && fromEmail.invalid">
                                        <div *ngIf="fromEmail.errors &&(fromEmail.touched || fromEmail.dirty)" class ="alert alert-danger">
                                            <div [hidden]="!fromEmail.errors?.pattern">
                                              Invalid pattern
                                            </div> 
                                        </div> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

and my .ts code is :

```
  onSubmit() {
    
         if (!this.currentForm.subscribers.subscriber[0].fromEmail){
            console.log('fromEmail required');
            this.currentForm.form.controls['fromEmail'].setErrors({'incorrect': true});
      
            return false;
          }
                  
            else{
        this.submitted = true;
          let requestBody={fromEmail:this.currentForm.subscribers.subscriber[0].fromEmail }
          console.log(requestBody); 
     this.userService.editSubscriber(this.currentForm.subscribers.subscriber[0].subscriberId,requestBody).subscribe(
  
  (_response) => {  alert('Subscriber edited successfully ' );})
    
     }
```

Comment: you should use subscribe the form control's valueChanges and then updateValueAndvalidity

Comment: yes I added the  subscribe but I think it did not paste in the question